# jQuery and label input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="one">
    <label for="number">Number</label>
    <div id="two">
        <input id="number" type="text" name="number">
    </div>   
</div>
```

This show me:

1. Number
2. [input]

How can I make:

1. Number [input]

How can I modify this with jQuery? (not modify html)

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/UBx6p/

Comment: Modify CSS -- http://jsfiddle.net/Jayendra/UBx6p/1/

Comment: Modifying the CSS wold be the most straightforward thing to do. Do you have access to it?

Comment: Why would you want to modify it with jQuery and not HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you really should change the HTML as stated above by Xavi.

If that is out of the question, you can perform the HTML changes via jQuery:

```
$('#one label').css('float', 'left');
$('#one #two').css('float', 'left');
$('#one #two').css('margin-left', '5px');
$('#one').append('<div style="clear:both"></div>');
```

put it here : http://jsfiddle.net/UBx6p/8/

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`.

```
<div id="one">
    <label for="number">Number</label>
    <span id="two">
        <input id="number" type="text" name="number">
    </span>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use CSS rather than javascript?

```
#two {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it only in JS. Then as suggested use something like this

```
document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'inline';
```